# Can a pregnant woman go to aquariums?

Tags: minhag, animals, pregnancy-birth, fish

Some have the custom that pregnant women do not go to zoos. (See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/is-there-an-issue-with-ladies-going-to-the-zoo-when-they-are-pregnant))

Does this custom extend to aquariums too?

Comment: THere's no custom, a couple of sources speculated that thing as a measure of precaution.

Comment: @AlBerko It’s customary in some households to follow those sources on this topic

Comment: Presumably the minhag is because a roaring lion or other scary animal might frighten the woman and cause a miscarriage The Talmud says a dog could cause such a thing to happen - how much more so a lion. That concern would not apply to an aquarium