# Can pregnant women look at animals?

Tags: women, animals, pregnancy-birth

Ive heard that pregnant women should not look at animals. What is the inyan behind pregnant women not looking at animals?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/is-there-an-issue-with-ladies-going-to-the-zoo-when-they-are-pregnant

Comment: There are no concrete answers at that link

Comment: But it’s the same question

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but what good is a question without answers?

Comment: @Shababnik That's how this site works: one post per question. If you'd like to post a bounty at that question looking for more concrete answers, feel free.

Comment: If nobody was able to answer that question to your satisfaction, what makes you think they’ll be able to answer yours? This is what’s called a duplicate question.

Comment: That question was posted 12 years ago. It was probably forgotten about

Comment: Old questions are just as visible through Google, where most of our views come from

Comment: Understood. I'll remember for future reference. Thanks everyone.